# How to validate Email & Password input from EditText before registering user

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, email-validation

> How to validate Email & Password input from EditText  before
>   registering user using Android Studio...
>
> Email: must contain @ symbol and other general requirements Password:
>   must >6 digits.

[image]

Please modify this code.
My code is...

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button buttonRegister;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private TextView textViewSignin;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
        //profile activity here
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));
    }

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    buttonRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
    editTextEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    textViewSignin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewSignin);

    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewSignin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void registerUser(){
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //uset cannot go any further without entering password
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stopping execution further
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stopping execution further
        return;
    }

    //if validations are ok
    //we will first show progressbar
    progressDialog.setMessage("Registerating User...");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //user is successfully registered. we will start profile activity here
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication success. " + user.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Could not register. please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.hide();
                    }

                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v==buttonRegister){
        registerUser();
    }
    if(v==textViewSignin){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: in your xml, add inputtype attribute to EditText and for password, fetch the it programatically , using 'getText().toString()' and then check the length of this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this my friend**

```
 String emailAddress = etSignInEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    if (etSignInPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
        etSignInPassword.setError(getString("password minimum contain 6 character"));
        etSignInPassword.requestFocus();
    }
    if (etSignInPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        etSignInPassword.setError(getString("please enter password"));
        etSignInPassword.requestFocus();
    }
    if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailAddress).matches()) {
        etSignInEmail.setError(getString("please enter valid email address"));
        etSignInEmail.requestFocus();
    }
    if (etSignInEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        etSignInEmail.setError(getString("please enter email address"));
        etSignInEmail.requestFocus();
    }
    if (!emailAddress.equals("") &&
        etSignInPassword.getText().toString().length() >= 6 &&
        !etSignInPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals("") &&
        android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailAddress).matches()) {
       // do  your action
    }
```

Comment: Thanks brother I've edited my code according to your logic, its working perfect now...

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this.

`android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRES`

or

```
public static boolean EMailValidation(String emailstring) {
        if (null == emailstring || emailstring.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        Pattern emailPattern = Pattern
                .compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
        Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(emailstring);
        return emailMatcher.matches();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code for email field validation and password validation and check for minimum 8 characters in password field.

```
  if (isValidEmail(et_regemail.getText().toString())&&etpass1.getText().toString().length()>7){
      if (validatePassword(etpass1.getText().toString())) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Go Ahead".....
      }
      else{

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"InvalidPassword".....
       }

}else{

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Email".....
}


public boolean validatePassword(final String password){
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.* 
    [@#$%^&+=!])(?=\\S+$).{4,}$";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

    return matcher.matches();
}

public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    if (target == null)
        return false;

    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Very easy way
    
    
    
            String email = LogineditTextEmailAddress.getText().toString().trim();
            String pass = LogineditTextPassword.getText().toString();
    
            if (email.isEmpty()) {
                LogineditTextEmailAddress.setError("Enter an email address");
                LogineditTextEmailAddress.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
    
            if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                LogineditTextEmailAddress.setError("Enter a valid email address");
                LogineditTextEmailAddress.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
    
            //checking the validity of the password
            if (pass.isEmpty()) {
                LogineditTextPassword.setError("Enter a password");
                LogineditTextPassword.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
    
            if (pass.length() < 8) {
    
                LogineditTextPassword.setError("Password Length Must be 8 Digits");
                LogineditTextPassword.requestFocus();
                return;
    
    
            }
```